# how to enable or disable editable option using x-editable in yii cgridview?

Tags: php, yii, x-editable, cgridview

My cgridview is

```
               'name'=>'teamLeader_id', 
                'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
                'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:180px'),
                'editable' => array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("employee/assignToTeamLeader"),
                    'source' => $usersList,
                    'enabled' =>'$data->employeType == 1 ? false : true',
                    'success' => 'js: function(response) {
                        if(response.success == false){ 
                            console.log(response.message);
                            return response.message;
                        }
                    }',
                    'options' => array(
                    'ajaxOptions' => array('dataType' => 'json')
                    ),
                )
```

My problem is that when I check condition in enabled param it does not work at all. I don't know why? Any help would be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

x-editable seems to have only an attribute `disable`, so just use that :)

http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/widgets#Options

```
            'name'=>'teamLeader_id', 
            'class' => 'bootstrap.widgets.TbEditableColumn',
            'headerHtmlOptions' => array('style' => 'width:180px'),
            'editable' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'url' => Yii::app()->createUrl("employee/assignToTeamLeader"),
                'source' => $usersList,
                'disabled' =>'$data->employeType == 1 ? true : false',
                'success' => 'js: function(response) {
                    if(response.success == false){ 
                        console.log(response.message);
                        return response.message;
                    }
                }',
                'options' => array(
                'ajaxOptions' => array('dataType' => 'json')
                ),
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use

```
'apply' => '$data->employeType == 1 ? true : false',
```

I've found this on thhis page with editable column documentation... (look at the source code): http://x-editable.demopage.ru/?r=site/widgets#EditableField